# New Line breaks patternsearch?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using a simple query:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)
where c.customerRemark =~ '(?ui).*test.*' 
RETURN c
```

works absolutely fine when you have a one-liner text. The moment you insert in your data record a new line feed/break with enter the query fails and does not show the data record although the word test is within the data-field.
It seems cypher cannot see whats behind a line break?
Anybody has experiences to share or an idea how I can avoid this?

Expected result should be that all records with the word "test" inside the field customerRemarks should be found, no matter if 1 or more lines - as this is a field with normally much text.

I use Neo4j 3.1.1 with PHP 5.4, on Linux and Windowsserver.

Thanks
B

---

**EDITED**

Here are two statements to create two nodes:

```
CREATE (c:Customer {nodeID:1})
SET c.customerRemark = "This is a test - Node 1"
RETURN c

CREATE (c:Customer {nodeID:2})
SET c.customerRemark = "This is a test with a linebreak inside - Node 2 Here comes text: 
here was a linebreak"
RETURN c
```

The statement:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)
WHERE c.customerRemark =~ '(?ui).*Node.*'
RETURN c
```

Returns only Node 1 instead of Node 1 and 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the flags `m` ([multiline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE)) and `s` ([dotall](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)) to your regex.

```
MATCH (c:Customer) where c.customerRemark =~ '(?muis).*Node.*' RETURN c
```

Comment: Not sure if I am doing something wrong but adding the m-flag did not solve the issue with the two nodes above, at least not on my test system. Did it worked at yours?

Comment: @Balael not, you are right. I updated my answer and added the `s` (DOTALL) flag too.

Comment: Amazing, that did the trick :) Thanks for this, very appreciated!